# Real Time Verification of credit card holder using autorize.net and asp.net(c#)

Tags: authorize.net

In my project I am using authorize.net  AIM & CIM feature for payment processing, I want to implement real time verification of card holder during transaction using authorize.net & asp.net (C#) in order to provide higher level of security and avoid fraud transaction. I am doing R&D  on this to have most prominent solution which will support for all types of credit card such Visa, Master Card,American Express, Discover etc.

Kindly provide help on this.

Thanks

Comment: From what I understand, you just want to verify if the card is valid or not ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just want to verify if the card is valid or not, in other term you want to authorize a transaction.
For that Authorize.Net provides with API specifically known as Authorize Only

You can look into : http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-authorize-a-credit-card

It has the sample request XML as well as sample codes, have a look into it.

Comment: No, I do not want to authorize transaction in fact I want to verify user who is doing transaction using credit card in real time so that I can confirm this is valid card holder and should allow to do transaction & not using any stolen credit card details to make fraud transaction.

Comment: Consider a use case where I am on a family holiday in a foreign country. I give my card to a relative for doing some shopping. He pays using the card and provides his own name in the billing info. Can you explain to me what you are trying to do in order to validate that the card was not stolen in this scenario ?

Comment: According to your scenario explained above , you are intentionally providing all your card details along with sensitive information to your relative. In this case, you are knowing that your relative is going to do transaction by using your card details.In this case transaction will be done successful as he entered all correct information.  Now, I want to validate user in real time so that he do not use credit card without card holder permission. i.e I want to implement  such security measure so that only valid card  holder able to do transaction after submitting correct sensitive information.

Comment: Hi, consider another scenario where my friend had stolen my credit card details and done transactions successfully after this,when my card was charged I came to know that this particular transaction was not done by me but done by some one else without my permission. (i.e Unauthorized Person) . How can we provide real time security  to handle  such scenarios so that only authorized person can use his credit card for transaction with respect to authorize.net ?.